# C++: Friend specific objects (nested classes)

Tags: c++, class, object, friend, nested-class

Say I have a class called `class AI`. And inside this class I created another child class called `class AIbrain`. Now, I want each separate `AI` object to be able to operate their own `AIbrain`. But if I `class AIbrain{friend AI;};` the class `Aibrain` will be exposed to every object of the class `AI`.

So I was wondering is there a way of an `AIbrain` friending their own `AI` object? Or else each `AI` will be able to modify any other `AI`'s variables and access their functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly:

```
class AI
{
    class AIbrain
    {
    } brain;
};
```

You want `brain` to be able to access its parent instance of `AI` (code examples make a lot clearer what you want to achieve by the way).

If this is the case you could solve this by:

```
class AI
{
        class AIbrain
        {
                AI * parent_;
                explicit AIbrain(AI * parent) : parent_(parent) {}
        } brain;

    public:
         AI() : brain(this) {}
};
```

If `brain` needs to access private members of the `AI` parent instance, you still need to declare `AIbrain` as a friend of `AI`. Since `AIbrain` is a member of `AI`, it is not necessary to declare `AI` a friend of `AIbrain`. Note that this is used here as a trick to prevent users from instantiating `AIbrain` directly (private constructor is accessable only for `AI`).

Answer (score 2):

You don't modify the variables and functions of a class (unless they are static) you modify those of an instance.

If you simple want each `AI` to *have a* `AIBrain`, give each AI instance an AI member

```
class AIBrain { /*...*/ };
class AI {
  public:
  //whatever
  private:
    AIBrain brain;
};
```

Each AI instance then has its own brain and can use the brain's public members and functions.